# Is it possible to use retrofit2, ViewModels, Corroutines and LiveData in API 22?

Tags: android, retrofit2, viewmodel, android-livedata, coroutine

I need to make an app for API 22 devices.

I mean I find myself in the need to use compileSDK = 22

Can somebody tell me if I can use Retrofit2, ViewModels, Corroutine, LiveData and ConstraintLayout in than app?

Has anyone worked with any of these features in an application compiled for API 22?

Or would it really be enough to just change tagetSDK to 22 and leave compileSDK at 32?

I thank you in advance for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

I made tests, and work perfectly.

It is not necessary to change compileSDK to 22, only had to change tagetSDK to 22.

Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).